# Cookies not setting in IE or Chrome

Tags: php, cookies

I have these two cookies that I am setting, they work in firefox but no where else, I have no idea why and I've been googling my ass off trying to find an answer...here are my cookies

```
setcookie("expire", 'Baldhead' , time() + 1800, "/");
setcookie("baldhead", 'Baldhead' , time() + 7200, "/");
```

Why are they not working?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled on all browsers in your testing environment?

Comment: in chrome i have my cookies set to Allow local data to be set (recommended)

Comment: How do you know that the cookies aren't set?

Comment: if you inspect element and go under resource you can see which cookies are being set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just this

```
setcookie("expire",'Baldhead',time()+1800);
setcookie("baldhead",'Baldhead',time()+7200);
```

Hope this works for you .

Comment: So there is something wrong on your side, do you use variables instead while testing ? as if you do so you should use another syntax .

Comment: I think its with the time() function

Comment: Âs I said, they work perfectly on my site so I just don't know why not on your service, is Cookies enabled on your browsers so they could work .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that this is the first thing being output from your script!

It's being sent through HTTP headers.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

More of your source would help out, so we could see the context in which it's being generated.

Comment: what do u mean by make sure that this is the first thing being output from your script? and how to can I tell if its being sent throught HTTP headers? there is not much more of the source...its a php controller page

Comment: It is being sent through HTTP headers.  The link that I sent you was the PHP documentation for this specific function.  HTTP headers have to be the first things that are output to the browser.